# CQWP grouping with custom order

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

Can anyone show me how to customise the order that the CQWP 'Groups By", We group Project Sites by Project Phases(from each project site List) and that's all good- but we need them in a specific project Phase order not Ascending/Descending

so:

Concept Project title Initiation Project title Planning Project title Execution Project title

instead of:

Concept Project title Execution Project title Initiation Project title Planning Project title

I can't find anything specific to this only: http://www.myphotoadventures.nl/2013/11/05/sharepoint-custom-grouping-with-xslt/ Thanks